# How to make Table and Figure side by side appear at the same height?

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I wrote the following code to make a table and a figure appear side by side:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{capt-of}% or \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{varwidth}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l l|}
            \hline
                2 Amenity & 3 Barrier \\ 
                4 Boundary & 5 Building  \\ 
                6 Craft & 7 Emergency \\ 
                8 Geological & 9 Highway \\ 
                10 Historic & 11 Landuse \\ 
                12 Leisure & 13 Man made \\ 
                14 Military & 15 Natural \\ 
                16 Office & 17 Place \\ 
                18 Power & 19 Transport \\ 
                20 Railway & 21 Route \\ 
                22 Shop & 23 Sport \\ 
                24 Tourism & 25 Waterway \\ 
                26 Aerialway & 27 Aeroway \\ 
            \hline 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.35]{OSMTreeDendrogram.png}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Tree representation of localities and their location types given by the Open Street Map.}
    \label{OSM_tree}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

It works, but they are not at the same height. They appear like this:

[image]

How do I make the table start at the same height as the figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tabular}{|l l|}
        \hline
    2 Amenity       & 3 Barrier \\
    4 Boundary      & 5 Building  \\
    6 Craft         & 7 Emergency \\
    8 Geological    & 9 Highway \\
    10 Historic     & 11 Landuse \\
    12 Leisure      & 13 Man made \\
    14 Military     & 15 Natural \\
    16 Office       & 17 Place \\
    18 Power        & 19 Transport \\
    20 Railway      & 21 Route \\
    22 Shop         & 23 Sport \\
    24 Tourism      & 25 Waterway \\
    26 Aerialway    & 27 Aeroway \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
&
\includegraphics[scale=0.35,valign=m]{OSMTreeDendrogram.png}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tree representation of localities and their location types given by the Open Street Map.}
\label{OSM_tree}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Instead of minipages I use`tabular` environment and for vertical align option `valign=m` from package `adjustbox`. Is this what you looking for?

[image]

**Addendum:** 
if you like to have vertically aligned the top of table and image (I overlooked this in your question, sorry) than you need to change:

- `\begin{tabular}{|l l|}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{|l l|}` and
- `\includegraphics[scale=0.35,valign=m]{OSMTreeDendrogram.png}` to `\includegraphics[scale=0.35,valign=T]{OSMTreeDendrogram.png}`.

Result is then the following:

[image]

I prefer the first solution :)

Comment: It doesn't make the 2 floats start from the same height, but at least now it looks better than what I had.

Comment: @Kristada673, see addendum to my answer. Not table in image are aligned at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Another sample code (with an option to resize the table) which places a table and figure side by side.

```
  \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
      \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
          \hline
          Test 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & Test 2 \\
          \hline
          0 & 224 &  &  &  &  & 224\\
          \hline
          1 & 58 & 57 &  &  &  & 115\\
          \hline
          2 & 26 & 27 & 27  &  &  & 80\\
          \hline
          3 & 16 & 16 & 15 & 15 &  & 62\\
          \hline
          4 & 10 & 10 & 11 & 10 & 10 & 51\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
      }
      \includegraphics[scale=0.35, valign=m]{fig.png}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{Table with data and its graph shown side by side}
    \label{tab:data_and_fig}
  \end{table}
```

[image: It should look like this now.]